# Python + Stripe.js payment integration gives error Invalid payment_page id

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate payments into my webapp using Stripe Checkout. I've followed the guide on [their website](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/api), and when I call `stripe.checkout.Session.create` it redirects me to the payment page https://checkout.stripe.com/pay/xxx but never loads. I've read the network requests using Chrome's F12 and i'm getting this info back.

> {error: {message: "Invalid payment_page id: test123", type: "invalid_request_error"}}

The Stripe documentation states that an `id` must be included when redirecting to checkout. I've then just setup a temporary string named `"test123"` but it doesn't seem like this is a valid one. How would I go on from here?

My current code (Python)

```
stripe.api_key = "sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
stripe.api_version = "2018-11-08; checkout_sessions_beta=v1"

stripe.checkout.Session.create(
  success_url="https://mypage.com/success",
  cancel_url="https://mypage.com/cancel",
  payment_method_types=["card"],
   client_reference_id="test123", #not sure if this one is needed
  line_items=[
    {
      "amount": 2000,
      "quantity": 2,
      "name": "Blue banana",
      "currency": "usd",
    }
  ]
)
```

js code on my html page

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script>
var stripe = Stripe(
  'pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxx',
  {
    betas: ['checkout_beta_4']
  }
);
</script>

<script>
stripe.redirectToCheckout({
  sessionId: "test123",
}).then(function (result) {
  // Diplay result.error.message to your customer
});
</script>
```

Screenshot of the infinite loading loop where I found the error inside the network tab.
[image]

**Edit:** I've also just noticed that when the following script is inside my HTML then it immediatly redirects users to Stripe checkout. How can I stop it from doing this and only happen when the Submit/Pay button is pressed.

**Edit 2** I've found out that to my upper edit that I need to create an event handler/listener. I will research that myself, no need to answer that part although greatly appreciated.

```
<script>
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      sessionId: "test123",
    }).then(function (result) {
      // Diplay result.error.message to your customer
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: You're passing `test123` instead of the session id in `redirectToCheckout` when you should pass what you get back in `stripe.checkout.Session.create`

Comment: @dan-klasson How would I grab the session ID in `stripe.checkout.Session.create`? I'm no expert at coding yet, if you could give me an idea or something i'll do some googling and research.

Comment: I'm guessing you get that id from what `stripe.checkout.Session.create` returns. Then pass that to your template and then grab it with JS and send to Stripe

Comment: You're right. I just did my code in `python -i` and it returns an ID. I'll try and figure out how to retrieve it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
payment = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
  success_url="https://mypage.com/success",
  cancel_url="https://mypage.com/cancel",
  payment_method_types=["card"],
  line_items=[
    {
      "amount": 2000,
      "quantity": 2,
      "name": "Blue banana",
      "currency": "usd",
    }
  ]
)   
context = payment.id
```

`Printing(payment.id)` returns the response ID from stripe. I saved this variable and added it as a context to use as a variable in my HTML. Page is now fully loading.